# Split table to sheet by column - don't work with numeric value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro to split table into sheets by column:

```
Dim DR As Range
Sheets("Budget").Select
Set DR = Range("DR")

For Each cell In DR
Sheets("Budget").Copy after:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("MasterData")
.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next cell

End Sub
```

It works when there are text values in column like for example names of regional directiors (column 9 is DR - regional director) and range DR is a list of all directors without duplicates. But when I tried the same with column number 10 which is regional director number I doesn't work... I checked it many times with other columns and it olny works when there's a text value in a column. How to fix it? Why it doesn't work when there's a number in a column? It doesn't work even when I converted this number to text (number as text value).

Comment: Can you be more specific? What doesn't work? Does a line error, and if so what is the error message?

Comment: There's no error. Table in a new sheet it's just empty. The marco should delete all rows and left only one for example first number of regional director like it works with the first director on the list. 
So sth gets wrong with this line .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete because after delete nothing left...

Comment: Don't think we have very much to go on ...

Comment: Ok to be more specific. I think the problem is with this line of code ```.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues```
I mean when I run macro step by step and DR range and filtered field is a text it works fine. But when DR and filtered field is a number it doesn't work fine it doesn't filter but shows all data. So it the end the next line of code deletes all rows and tables in a new sheets are empty...

Comment: @BigBen, I tried to be more specific above. Seems like there's a problem when it comes to filter numbers not text.